# What is the mass of 1 Liter of ethylene at 2000 bar pressure?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws

I was wondering the weight of 1 liter of ethylene at 2000 bar and 310 Kelvin?

I have tried to just multiply the weight at 1 bar with 2000 but I don't think i got the correct answer because the answer I got was just below 2.4 kg per liter which seems way too high.

I calculated it with constant temperature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we treat it as an ideal gas, then
\begin{aligned}
  PV &= n\mathcal{R}T \\ \mathcal{R} &=0.08314~\mathrm{L~bar~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}}\\
  n &=\frac{PV}{\mathcal{R}T}=\frac{2000\cdot1}{0.08314\cdot310}=77.6~\mathrm{mol}\\
  M(\ce{ethylene}) &=28~\mathrm{g~mol^{-1}}\\
  \text{mass of ethylene} &= (28\cdot77.6) = 2.17~\mathrm{kg}
\end{aligned}

**Edit:**
 Using the link<sup>[a]</sup> in the comment I find that the density of ethylene at $310~\mathrm{K}$ and $1800~\mathrm{bar}$ is $\varrho = 20.385~\mathrm{mol/L}$, and $\varrho = 21.065~\mathrm{mol/L}$ at $2200~\mathrm{bar}$.  Averaging these two numbers gives an estimated density of $\varrho = 20.725~\mathrm{mol/L}$ at $310~\mathrm{K}$ and $2000~\mathrm{bar}$.  So 1 liter of ethylene under these conditions would contain 
\begin{aligned}
  \varrho\cdot M_{\ce{C2H4}}\cdot V & ~= m_{\ce{C2H4}}\\
  20.725~\mathrm{\frac{mol}{L}} \cdot 28~\mathrm{\frac{g}{mol}}\cdot 1~\mathrm{L} & ~\approx 580~\mathrm{g}.\\
\end{aligned}
  Is that more in line with your expectations?

[a] Majid Jahangiri, Richard T Jacobsen, Richard B. Stewart and Robert D. McCarty: Thermodynamic Properties of Ethylene from the Freezing Line to 450 K at Pressures to 260 MPa. [*J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data* **1986**, *15 (2)*, 593](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.555753). (DOI:10.1063/1.555753) ([mirror at www.nist.gov](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd294.pdf))

Comment: I like your answer, but I am curious if ethylene at $200~\mathrm{bar}$ is still a gas. (I would tend to liquid) Also I do not really think at these pressures any gas will behave ideal, probably not even helium.

Comment: I thought about the gas-liquid question.  Since a volume was given I went with gas.  If it was liquid and we "assume" (I know) incompressibility - well it seemed too straightforward.  But yes, whether a gas or a liquid, probably far from ideal.

Comment: Here at work we have compressors that compress the gas to 2300 bars and the compressor can only handle 30% liquid so it is not a liquid, at least not in the sense that it can still be compressed but one of the engineers her found that there was something called "compressibility factor" which seem to have a lot of influence on the answer.

Comment: Someone linked this [link](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd294.pdf) at the physics section of this site it has the answer

Comment: If I take the molar density that is given in the tables on that site and multiply it by the molar weight of ethylene I get 28.05g/mol * 20.065 mol/dm^3 = 562.82325 g/dm^3   . 
This is at 310 K

Comment: 20.065, do you mean 21.065?

Comment: Wow, that is a horrible deviation. I wonder if you would get any closer by applying the [van der Waals equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation): $$\left(p + \frac{n^2 a}{V^2}\right)\left(V-nb\right) = nRT.$$

Comment: The [compressibility factor $Z$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility_factor) is just a empirical way to describe non-ideal gasses by slightly modifying the ideal gas equation. For ideal gasses, $\frac{pV}{nRT}=1$, but for non-ideal gasses the ratio can be either smaller or larger than 1. By performing experiments in different conditions, it is possible to approximately tabulate values of $Z$ and attempt to interpolate/extrapolate. For gasses in conditions close to ideal (high temp, low pressure), $Z$ varies quite smoothly, but at extreme conditions it probably behaves very erratically

Comment: I did look for Z values for ethylene, but couldn't find anything around 2000 bars.